# Cordova on Android doesn´t open PDF links (and doesn´t show "Open in..." dialog)

Tags: android, cordova, pdf

I have a Cordova App with InAppBrowser and Whitelist Plugin. Unfortunately links to PDF files will not loaded in the webview and the user don´t see an "Open File in..." dialog to open this files with a system App

Here are some values of my config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" />
<access launch-external="yes" origin="whatsapp:*"/>
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

I understand, that Android doesn´t support to display PDF files in a webview. But how can I trigger Cordova to show the "Open file in...(installed System App)" dialog?

Comment: Please read this answer that will help u  . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462707/if-link-is-http-google-com-it-worked-but-if-i-change-link-to-my-pdf-url-i/38463242?noredirect=1#comment64330780_38463242

Answer (score 0):

For android, you may download it first locally

```
$http.get(url, {
 responseType: 'blob'
})
.success(function (blob) {
  $cordovaFile.writeFile(path, filename, blob, true)
    .then(function (file) {
      // open the file
      $cordovaFileOpener2.open(file.nativeURL.split('file://').pop(), 'application/pdf');
    });
});
```

It will trigger the open with on android or open the default pdf viewer if its already set. You may add some file checking to be sure it got download. $cordovaFileTransfer may work now, but at the time I was trying to use it, it didnt work properly.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Sorry, I forgot that I´m looking for a solution in android code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution in Android Code. Setting a WebViewClient in onCreate and checking which URL was clicked. For a PDF-Link I send it to the system default App
Very basic checking, if the link is a PDF. Could be improved.

```
    WebView cordovaView = (WebView) this.appView.getView();

    cordovaView.setWebViewClient(new SystemWebViewClient((SystemWebViewEngine) this.appView.getEngine()){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.contains(".pdf"))
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
url = "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="+YOUR_PDF_LINK;
var documentLink = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no,hardwareback=yes');

documentLink.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {

});

documentLink.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {
    documentLink.removeEventListener("loadstart", function(e){});
});
```