# If link is 'http://google.com', it worked, but if i change link to my pdf url, it doesn't open

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, pdf

`window.open("http://google.com")` - works fine

`window.open("data:application/pdf;base64,{base64EncodedString}")` - opens fine on iOS device but not on Android.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a debug platform, it's a Q&A. Show us what you tried, what happens when opened on android(Error? Blank page) , if you're using Xamarin or Java, etc.

Comment: I don't see any errors. The application just does not respond to the click.

Comment: For the love of God, are you using Java or Xamarin? What have you tried? We aren't fortune tellers.

Comment: It's Apache Cordova

Comment: Any logs or anything?

Answer (score 0):

Please use plugin file opener for that .Here is the plugin .

run this command in your working  directory .

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-opener2
```

basic usage

PDF File opener code

```
cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
    '/sdcard/Download/starwars.pdf', // You can also use a Cordova-style file uri: cdvfile://localhost/persistent/Download/starwars.pdf
    'application/pdf', 
    { 
        error : function(e) { 
            console.log('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
        },
        success : function () {
            console.log('file opened successfully');                
        }
    }
);
```

Please also check this url it is the plugin git directory and also have some example to open files.
[A File Opener Plugin for Cordova](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2)

---

I would also suggest using In App Browser plugin.

You can install it by running:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser
```

in your CLI (in case if you are using Cordova 3.x).
Earlier versions such (2.8.0, 2.9.0 etc) should have it pre-installed.

Ton open PDF documents in a new window use:

window.open('http://your-url.com/yourPDF.pdf', '_blank');
You might be able to use '_system option instead of '_blank' but i'm not sure about the outcome, it might open a system defined PDF viewer

Comment: Why is it required to use a third party plugin?

Comment: In App Browser plugin also required to use it as it is.

Comment: You keep saying required - my question is why? Why is opening a PDF not possible in Android?

Comment: sorry for inconvenience but we arent able to open a pdf file without these plugins. Thanks

Comment: Please now check out the whole answer hopefully it will help u .

Comment: @HassanALi - Can I pass base64 encoded pdf string to this to open the PDF?

Comment: its didnt need any more as you can see 'application/pdf',  we already had mention about our file type . But you try for sake of your testing.I haven't tried it yet. Sorry

Answer (score -1):

Looks like I have to use

window.location.href = "data:application/pdf;base64,{base64EncodedString}"

instead of window.open("data:application/pdf;base64,{base64EncodedString}");